# Laravel: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object for Auth::User()->id;

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following login controller :

```
public function userLogin(Request $request) {

    $rules = [
        'email' => 'required|exists:users',
        'password'  => 'required'
    ];
    $request->validate($rules);
    $data = [
        'email' => $request->get('email'),
        'password'  =>  $request->get('password'),
    ];

    if(Auth::attempt($data))
    {
        $user = Auth::User();
        $userid = Auth::User()->id;
        
        return response()->json([
            'user'  =>  $user, 
            'token' =>  $user->createToken('yourAppName')->accessToken ,

             $userid
        ]);

    }
    else
    {
        return response()->json('Unauthorized', 401);
    }

}
```

My `web.php` ( Token is generated with Laravel Passport )

```
Route::get('/customize/{id}', function ($id) {
 
    if (
        User::where('id', Auth::User()->id)->whereHas('profile', function ($query) use ($id) {
            return $query->where('id', $id);
        })
        ->exists()
    )  {
        return view( 'welcome' );
      }      
      return "no";
});
```

For some reason, when testing my `logincontroller` with **POSTMAN**, I actually receive a value for `Auth::User()->id` . But in `web.php` I receive `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`. Any idea ?

Comment: have you tried to move the code to `api.php` instead of `web.php`? the API and web session are not shared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a solution

you can find that user in db with email and password you have and get its id

and then use LoginUsingId($id) to login your user

Answer (score 0):

Find out why you are **not** considered as an **authenticated** user. I can guess you send Authentication token in your **request headers** when you use Postman. that this is not possible when you hit the address in the browser directly.

Comment: I'm passing only `email` and `password` in Postman.

Comment: You are right I'm not considered as authenticated. I checked with  `if (Auth::check()){return response()->json(['Passed']);}else{return response()->json('Error', 401);}` in my controller and had error. But I don't know why. I'm using React to login btw and not the default Laravel login.